# How to access string (which is in view controller) from the app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

In view controller, i'm going to store parameters(`token` &`edriver_id`) in response object  from server. i'm able to store that in 2 string e.g.`fetchtokenString` and `fetchedriveridString`... like following

```
        NSLog(@"Response from server 1 :  %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);


    NSError *error;
    NSArray *temp = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    // in this line we assingn the current value to global value
    _tokenString = [[temp objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"token"];
    _edriveridString = [[temp objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"edriverId"];
```

I need to know , How to access that 2 string (which is in view controller) from app delegate... i have no idea about this and i don't know to implement this..please help me.

and i want to access this two string from App delegate... how can i do this??

Comment: "MVC"  The view controller is the "VC" bit and you should store your data in the model bit ("M").  Just make the model bit globally-available; like a singleton or something.

Comment: @trojanfoe i didn't get it properly... can you post what do you mean..please.

Comment: you can create a model object , and store values in that, and you can acces these value in all over your app, and you can also use NSUSERDEFAULTS tosave values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suraj,

Why store those variables inside your class and then access it in app delegate when you can actually store those values directly in appDelegate ??? Create two public variables tokenString and edriveridString in appdelegate access appdelegate from your class which should not be difficult and then acees them directly in appdelegate :)

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.tokenString = [[temp objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"token"];
appDelegate.edriveridString = [[temp objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"edriverId"];
```

Now the data is with appdelegate access it whenever you want :) and bonus it is now accessible to all :) And AppDelegate is singleton as well :) so no fear of multiple instances of variables in memory :)

Comment: solve my issue by using this answer.... but may i know,why this answer get is down vote?.... any problem in that?

Comment: @suraj-sukale : There is nothing wrong in answer :) It was down voted by trojanfoe if you read his comment carefully he is not saying its wrong answer :) He is just saying you should not use app delegate as model class :) rather you should create a singleton class and save these variables in that singleton class :) He is asking you to follow proper MVC :) Though I agree with his perspective but it is not essential thing to do :)

Comment: If you have ever used coredata :) You will notice that managedObject context property which is created and pre configured by apple lies in AppDelegate itself. Intention is to make managedObjectContext singleton and accessible to all :) Though apple could have also created a singleton class and created a property there they wont do it as its not that big design pattern breach :) This no way justifies that you should create a property in appdelegate but neither says creating one is wrong buddy :) Its just the perspective and coding practice you follow :) Happy coding :) you can accept it :)

Comment: @suraj-sukale : Am glad you solved it feel free to accept or up vote the answer if you are benifited by it :) Happy coding :)

Comment: I would be biased as I have posted a different answer, but - yes you should not be storing properties on the AppDelegate, not really.  Its more normal that the properties are View properties, if they are created and used by the view.  Thats why I suggest that the view is the owner of these, and the AppD gets access to them as I describe below.  Yes this answer works but its not a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: @luke-smith : Though I have multiple times specified that my answer does not say its ok to store value in appDelegate :) Lemme point out one small thing here buddy he is saving token string and deviderString to be honest I dont really think its a viewController property or the property only a singleViewController is concerned :) Just a guess :) And I absolutely second your thoughts :) Hence the up-vote :) I have never said its a good design pattern to save data in appDelegate all I am saying is doing that isn't a mistake either :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari thanks for the upvote.  Yeh I agree with you, its not clear who is best to choose for the ownership of the property.  Depends on what else its being used for eh.  Coredata might be a good candidate but maybe overkill for his problem.  It also depends on when and where he needs it - if he needs it after the VC has gone, then the AppD wont be able to get it, so my solution doesnt work!  We need more code to decide, but I can see how your solution has advantages over mine too :)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of steps here.  First, ensure that those properties that you want to access in the ViewController are defined in the header file.

Then its a question of how your views are structured.  Do you use a navigation controller for eg?  If so, within the AppDelegate, you can probably access the navigation controller like this :

`UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;`

Then with that navController, you can get access to your UIViewController.  First ensure that the class has been imported for use :

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
```

Then you can get access to your view controller :

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

And then access your property from that view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Following are options:

- SINGLETON
- NSUSERDEFAULTS

Answer (score -1):

```
// **AppDelegate is a singleton class, its is access any where in view controller.**

    **//crete a variable global in AppDelegate. in**

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *tokenString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* edriveridString;

// **you can assign the value in AppDelegate.m**

_tokenString = [[temp objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"token"];
_edriveridString = [[temp objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"edriverId”];

// In View Controller where you want to access this value , write.

AppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@“tokenString -> %@“, del.tokenString);
NSLog(@“ edriveridString-> %@“, del. edriveridString);
```

Comment: So use the AppDelegate as the model class, just because it's already a singleton?  Lazy coding.

Answer (score -1):

Store these strings in AppDelegate and access them in any view controller in your application.

Write the lines below in AppDelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *tokenString;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * edriveridString;
```

Store these strings in AppDelegate and access them in any view controller in your application. declare in AppDelegate.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *tokenString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* edriveridString;

And set values in these variables :

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication  sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.tokenString = [[temp objectAtIndex:0]    valueForKey:@"token"];
appDelegate.edriveridString = [[temp objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"edriverId"];
```